# How can I load a specific css file in a specific case with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to:

```
// Display loader spinner
// Check if ID or Class exist in HTML Page
// If ID or Class are found, load a specific css file
// Display HTML PAGE
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Please do not ask "is that possible"? Some people might take you literally and answer "Yes" (which will almost always be the answer, since we are working with computers, for which most things are possible). If you want to know how to do something, then ask how to do it. Also, please ask one question at a time. The spin loader is a completely distinct issue from dynamically loading CSS. Finally, there is no need to specify "Vanilla JS". That is the default unless you specify some specific framework or library.

Comment: Look like peoples understand what i ask

Comment: I'm not killing you. I'm making helpful suggestions. If you choose not to accept them, so be it. Another helpful suggestion: take helpful suggestions.

Comment: Thank you i will take the suggestion ! I Just joking :) ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript this how you check if a class exists in a page:

```
var isClassExist = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass');
if (isClassExist .length > 0) {
    // elements with class "yourClass" exist
}
```

And this is how you append a css file to a page:

```
var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
if (!document.getElementById(cssId))
{
    var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.id   = cssId;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet.css';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

The loader part:

You first have to include your spinner in the html:

```
<div id="dvReqSpinner" style="display: none;">
    <br />
    <center><img src="~/images/loading_spinner.gif" /></center>
    <br />
</div>
```

Then in JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$("#dvReqSpinner").hide();
```

Comment: `var checkButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
       if (checkClasses .length > 0) {
        // Load CSS Files from assets/stylesheet/shortcodes/buttons/button.min.css
       } else {
        // Pass to next
       }` I will put your complete append script in if ?

Comment: Exactly. You have to put the second code snippet within the `if`

Comment: But what about spin loader :) . If i can ask you, how do i  can integrate it !?

Comment: I'm glad it helped, I will answer you later about the loader.

Answer (score 2):

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/4nw7wbs5/).

```js
// Let's load the bootstrap CSS, for example.
var css_file_path = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css?" + (new Date()).getTime();

function show_spinning_loader() {
  var el = document.createElement("div")
  el.id = "overlay";
  el.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin spin-small"></i>';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
}

function hide_spinning_loader() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  if (overlay) {
    overlay.outerHTML = "";
    delete overlay;
  }
}

function remove_class(name) {
  document.body.className =
    document.body.className
    .replace(new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + name + '(?:\\s|$)'), ' ');
}

function css_load_callback(m) {
  hide_spinning_loader();
  remove_class('loading');
};

// Load the stylesheet.
var url = css_file_path,
  head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
  link = document.createElement('link');

link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = url;

// Show the loader.
show_spinning_loader();
document.body.className += " loading"

// Trigger stylesheet import.
head.appendChild(link);

// Listen for the DOM onreadystatechange event.
if (link.addEventListener) {
  link.addEventListener('load', function() {
    css_load_callback();
  }, false);
};

// Hide loader when done.
var cssnum = document.styleSheets.length;
var ti = setInterval(function() {
  if (document.styleSheets.length > cssnum) {
    css_load_callback();
    clearInterval(ti);
  }
}, 10);
```

```css
body.loading * {
  display: none;
}
body.loading #overlay {
  display: block;
}
#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#overlay i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.spin-small {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
<p>These styles were loaded from bootstrap.</p>
```